# Remind me to upvote (Add an 'I will try this'-button to answers)

Tags: feature-request, voting, reminder

### Idea

I think it would be a great idea to add a button by answers labeled "I will try this" that you can click to get reminders about voting on the answer.

### Why

When I have a problem, I often find possible solutions on Stack Overflow. But in many cases it's not so simple that you can instantly tell that you found the right answer.

You might need to do a bit of hacking, reconfiguring, testing, etc., before you now if you found the right answer or not.

Then life happens a bit and you forget to go back and upvote the answer that actually helped you (or add a new answer to the question).

So, my idea is to have a "I will try this"-button by the answers. When you are browsing answers and find something you want to try, you click it.

If you did not upvote that answer or add an own answer to that question within a day (?) you will get an email reminder to go back and vote.

Answer (score 10):

I doubt whether this is useful.

In my experience, keeping your browser open is enough to get back to the post in order to vote on it. Most browsers can restore your previous sessions even after closing the browser, so there is an easy way to be reminded.

If it seemed helpful and you want to revisit it, mark it as favorite. Then you will see it in your list until you decide what to do with it. I don't think we should clutter the UI and our mailboxes with this.

Comment: About cluttering the UI, I can slightly agree. Regarding the rest, we have differnt opinions: I do not think you should rely on users keeping tabs or browsers open. We want people to vote on answers, lets help them remember to do it. In the longer run, I also think the statistics can be useful for replies: How many have tried an answer but not succeded, etc.

Comment: Okay, but I have never had a case where I would need more than a few minutes / hour to check if the solution works or was feasible enough to vote up/down. And you always want to include a reference to the post you used in your code (as in 'attribution'). And still you have favorites.

Answer (score 7):

The recent Saves list feature ([Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/1242908)) makes this feature request no longer necessary as everything you describe can now simply be achieved by creating a Saves list titled "I will try this later" far more easily than with the previous "bookmarks" aka "favorites".

The second part of your feature request about a reminder to vote is really a separate issue. However, that is also unnecessary because you can create a private note when saving a post to a Saves list with any message reminder you like.

Answer (score 4):

You can use bookmarks, aka. favorites, for this purpose.  When you find such a Q&A, tick the little star/asterisk symbol under the vote count and it will be added for you.  This does not entail or require an upvote.

It's also handy if during your "bit of hacking, reconfiguring, testing, etc" you happen to lose track of the suggestion you were pursuing.

Either way, later on you can select "favorites" on your "Activity" page then sort by "newest" and you'll find everything you've recently ticked.  To remove one of them from the list -- because you're done expressing your gratitude, or realized you aren't going to have any -- tick the star/asterisk count in the left column and you now have one less bookmark (aka. favorite).